# Authenticating with non-default credentials in node.js GCP Secret Manager client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client, google-secret-manager

I am trying to to use the `@google-cloud/secret-manager` package to read secrets from inside an application, and I want it to authenticate with a specific service account, not the default credentials. I can't find any documentation anywhere on how to do this.

```
import { SecretManagerServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/secret-manager';

const smClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
```

There are no options anywhere in the docs to provide authentication parameters. I'm trying to even use the `google-auth-library` to authenticate with my service account, but I'm not sure how to even pass that to the secret-manager request.

```
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';

const keyFile = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../service-account.json'))
)

const authClient = new JWT({
    email: keyFile.client_email,
    key: keyFile.private_key,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Client Libraries use a library called **Application Default Credentials** (ADC) to automatically find your service account credentials. ADC looks for service account credentials in the following order:

- If the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** is set, ADC uses the service account key or configuration file that the variable points to.
- If it isn't set, ADC uses the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code.
- If ADC can't use any of the above credentials, an error occurs.

The recommended steps would be to create a **service account** and set an [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) accordingly. Also ,there are few examples for common [use cases](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/secret-manager/latest#using-the-client-library) and a brief information in the same document about how to access a secret.

Hope the above information is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking everywhere for a variable like that. I'm just doing by setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. However I'm still surprised there's no way to specify credentials. I'm coming from AWS and all their libraries can be manually passed credentials. What if I needed to access multiple accounts from one app?

Answer (score 0):

If your runtime environment has a built-in credential (because you are on Google Cloud or you use Workload Identity federation), you are going to the wrong way.

Service account key file (the json file) is insecure and I strong recommend to use it in only very specific cases.

But I understand the requirement to access a secret with another identity/credential. For that, something exist and it's named ["impersonation"](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#:%7E:text=Impersonating%20service%20accounts%20is%20when,impersonation%2C%20see%20Service%20account%20impersonation.).

The principle is to allow your current default credential generating a token (access or identity) on behalf another service account. For that, the current credential requires the role "Service Account Token Creator" to be able to generate that token.

I'm not a node.js developer, but I fount [that](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/google-auth-library/impersonated) and that piece of code

```js
  let targetClient = new Impersonated({
    sourceClient: <SourceCredential>,
    targetPrincipal: "impersonated-account@fabled-ray-104117.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    lifetime: 30,
    delegates: [],
    targetScopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
  });
```